# Word for a nonbinary person who can transform into a wolf

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

The word 'werewolf' contains the element 'were', which refers specifically to males. While there is a corresponding term for women, I have found no such elements regarding nonbinary people

Is there any word/word element that works here and is gender neutral or refers to nonbinary gender?

Example sentence: "the _______ transformed in the moon's light"

Comment: It is neither a wolfman nor a wolfwoman, it is a wolfperson.

Comment: Hollywood etc. may have invented werewoman but historically they were only men: https://theconversation.com/the-ancient-origins-of-werewolves-104775

Comment: The term has lost any gendered attachment; probably few are aware that 'were' here  almost certainly relates to << late Old English _werewulf_ "person with the power to turn into a wolf," from _wer_ "man, male person" >> [[Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/werewolf)] (though a certain author (female) has addressed this).

Comment: It is a nonbinary wolf?

Comment: When we find a man who can transform into a wolf, we will look for a nonbinary person who can transform into a wolf. Just saying. He and they cannot yet.

Answer (score 8):

Most definitions (e.g. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/werewolf)) will tell you that *werewolf* is gender-neutral, despite its etymology. The case is similar to that of the word *director*; though this word has a female counterpart (*directress*), it's almost never used, and we typically use the "male" version to refer to people of either gender. Indeed, sources seem to differ on whether a separate female version of *werewolf* exists; there is the term *werewoman,* but [as Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewoman) etymologically that would mean "man-woman," not "female werewolf."

That said, if you insist on using a different term, the best choice is **lycanthrope,** which [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/lycanthrope) defines simply as "werewolf."

Comment: I've heard "wifewolf" used for the specifically female lycanthrope.

Comment: That "werewoman" Wikipedia article is rather misleading.  It's not only the etymology of the term than implies a different meaning, but the real uses of the term.  Doing some quick googling, I found at least as many examples of *werewoman* used to mean a man who transforms into a woman.

Comment: *Lycanthrope* is etymologically *wolf-man*. And the *OED* cast doubt on *were* in *werewolf* being related to *man* at all. So I would stick with *werewolf* for those reasons (among many others).

Comment: @TinfoilHat The root *anthropos* means *human*; it isn't gendered.